# Apache Mina TCP session tracking from client

Tags: java, tcp, apache-mina

I have created a TCP client using Apache Mina. I have added a while loop to constantly check the liveness of the port. Once the connection is up on the server side, the loop is broken and the connection is made. i get the session from future and use it to communicate. 
Is there a better way to do this. instead of loop can i ask the connection to wait till its up.

```
 while(true){
   try {
 ConnectFuture future = ioConnector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Port),
            new TriggerReceiverHandler(), SOCKET_CONFIG);
    System.out.println("Message Receiver started and listening on port "+ Port);
Thread.sleep(1000);
                session = future.getSession();
                if(session != null)
                    break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception ce){
                if(ce.getCause() instanceof ConnectException)
                System.out.println("Retrying connection");
            }
        }
```

Another question is, If the server is down and I want the server to keep waiting for the connection till its up, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, As of now its not possible, as the connection state is known only when we attempt to connect. One modification is instead of the `Thread.sleep(1000);` we can add `future.join()` in version 1.0+ or add a listener for the future in case of 2.0+